# Alfresco: how to call share webscript from client js and extract JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, get, alfresco-share

From client-side javascript I want to call a share-webscript which returns JSON data.

The response from getTicket.json.ftl looks like:

```
{
   "ticket" : "TICKET_faf851d4a993b62c98908268af07876f09fa86c9"
}
```

So how can I call this share-webscript from my client-side javascript and extract the value of "ticket" ?

```
see answer below
```

Comment: what version of alfresco are you working with? I can't locate the uri of this webscript in the services index of all webscripts

Comment: 4.2.2 but I already got it by myselfe, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

```
Alfresco.util.Ajax.jsonGet(
                    {
                        url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "/auth/getTicket.json",
                        successCallback:
                        {
                            fn: function(response)
                            {
                                try {
                                    var json = JSON.parse(response.serverResponse.responseText);
                                    var ticket = json["ticket"];
                                    if (ticket.substring(0, 6) == "TICKET") {
                                        clipboardData.setData("Text", ticket + "&" + file.nodeRef);
                                        location.href = Alfresco.constants.URL_RESCONTEXT + "components/javawebstart/AEF_JNLP.jnlp";
                                    } else {
                                        // handle unknown format
                                    }
                                } catch (e) {
                                    // handle error
                                }

                            },
                            scope: this
                        },

                        failureCallback:
                        {
                            fn: function(response)
                            {
                                // handle failure case
                            },
                            scope: this
                        }
                    });
```

This calles the share tier webscript. So you also need a share tier webscript which calls a repository web script which returns the actual ticket ...